# Andorid jniLibs not getting packed in APK

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, apk

I've two shared libraries `libsample.so` and `libsycl.so.6` in `jniLibs/arm64-v8a` folder. Upon building and analyzing the apk, I could see only `libsample.so` got placed in APK's lib folder but not the `libsycl.so.6` (Refer image below).

If I remove the version in shared object and use `libsycl.so`, it's getting copied to APK's lib.

- Any reason for this behaviour?
- What changes do I need to make to place `libsycl.so.6` inside APK?

[image]

**Update** : Attching build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.syclsample'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.syclsample"
        minSdk 27
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk{
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++17 -fexceptions -frtti"
                arguments "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE",'-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared'
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
            version '3.22.1'

        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

**Update 2** :
As [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1524450/michael) suggested, Android studio seems to be ignoring versioned .so files. After little searching I found below solutions to be effective.

https://gist.github.com/Sotatek-TuyenLuu/2f89b2a6690989b0550ea7d409d4e9f3

[Link in Android Studio with shared libraries with versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62450784/link-in-android-studio-with-shared-libraries-with-versioning)

Comment: Show your gradle config

Comment: I don't believe versioned .so files are a thing on Android, so it's possible that anything that doesn't end with exactly `.so` is ignored.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, I've updated it possible solutions.